# Retrieving attention weights for sentences? Most attentive sentences are zero vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, attention-model

I have a document classification task, that classifies documents as good (1) or bad (0), and I use some sentence embeddings for each document to classify the documents accordingly.

**What I like to do is retrieving the attention scores for each document, to obtain the most "relevant" sentences (i.e., those with high attention scores)**

*I padded each document to the same length* (i.e., 1000 sentences per document). So my tensor for 5000 documents looks like this `X = np.ones(shape=(5000, 1000, 200))` (5000 documents with each having a 1000 sequence of sentence vectors and each sentence vector consisting of 200 features).

My network looks like this:

```
no_sentences_per_doc = 1000
sentence_embedding = 200

sequence_input  = Input(shape=(no_sentences_per_doc, sentence_embedding))
gru_layer = Bidirectional(GRU(50,
                          return_sequences=True
                          ))(sequence_input)
sent_dense = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='sent_dense')(gru_layer)  
sent_att,sent_coeffs = AttentionLayer(100,return_coefficients=True, name='sent_attention')(sent_dense)
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(sent_att)  
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[TruePositives(name='true_positives'),
                      TrueNegatives(name='true_negatives'),
                      FalseNegatives(name='false_negatives'),
                      FalsePositives(name='false_positives')
                      ])

history = model.fit(X, y, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

After training I retrieved the attention scores as follows:

```
sent_att_weights = Model(inputs=sequence_input,outputs=sent_coeffs)

## load a single sample
## from file with 150 sentences (one sentence per line)
## each sentence consisting of 200 features
x_sample = np.load(x_sample)
## and reshape to (1, 1000, 200)
x_sample = x_sample.reshape(1,1000,200) 

output_array = sent_att_weights.predict(x_sample)
```

*However,* if I show the top 3 attention scores for the sentences, I also obtain sentence indices that are, for example, `[432, 434, 999]` for a document that has only 150 sentences (the rest is padded, i.e., just zeros).

**Does that make sense or am I doing something wrong here?** (is there a mistake in my attention layer? Or is due to a low F-score?)

The attention layer I use is the following:

```
class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    """
    https://humboldt-wi.github.io/blog/research/information_systems_1819/group5_han/
    """
    def __init__(self,attention_dim=100,return_coefficients=False,**kwargs):
        # Initializer 
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.return_coefficients = return_coefficients
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform') # initializes values with uniform distribution
        self.attention_dim = attention_dim
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Builds all weights
        # W = Weight matrix, b = bias vector, u = context vector
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)),name='W')
        self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, )),name='b')
        self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)),name='u')
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.u]

        super(AttentionLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        return None

    def call(self, hit, mask=None):
        # Here, the actual calculation is done
        uit = K.bias_add(K.dot(hit, self.W),self.b)
        uit = K.tanh(uit)
        
        ait = K.dot(uit, self.u)
        ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)
        ait = K.exp(ait)
        
        if mask is not None:
            ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        ait = K.expand_dims(ait)
        weighted_input = hit * ait
        
        if self.return_coefficients:
            return [K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1), ait]
        else:
            return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.return_coefficients:
            return [(input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]), (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1], 1)]
        else:
            return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
```

Note that I use `keras` with `tensorflow` backend version 2.1.; the attention layer was originally written for theano, but I use `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`